# Adding Google charts to PDF using Itext7

Tags: itext7

How to add google charts to Itext7. Prepared google chats (ex : 10 charts) in HTML, i would like to add each chart to Table Cell (ex: 10 cells)  in Itext7. Please advise.

Comment: You wait a couple of weeks until the html2pdf add-on for iText 7 comes out, and then you add that add-on to your project. Meanwhile can you add the HTML of your charts to your question here, so we can verify in advance that it will work as expected? As an alternative, save your chart as a PNG image and add that image to a table cell.

Comment: Thanks for reply, any sample code or link for HTML and Itext7

Comment: I shall repeat myself: _wait a couple of weeks until the html2pdf add-on for iText 7 comes out_